# Channels Attention implementation

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, attention-model

I'm a novice in deep learning. I saw an implementation of attention mechanism for CNN from an article written by Analytics Vidhya available at https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/novel-techniques-to-win-an-image-classification-hackathon-part-3-e45900f8ca30

What value can be used for input_shape and ratio in "input_shape//ratio" as shown on the attached image. The input channel of the images I used is (224, 224, 3). Can these two values be gotten from this channel.[channel attention with python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9VVv.jpg)